# Creating Navbar from LESS to CSS without JS

Tags: html, css, less, navbar

I am trying to copy a navbar I found on codepen.

[This is what I want](https://codepen.io/mrmlnc/pen/gpKbXM)

```
// Scaffolding
*, *:before, *:after { box-sizing: border-box; }
body { background-color: #f5f5f5; color: #333; font-size: 14px; font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 20px; }
a { text-decoration: none; transition: all 0.3s linear 0s; }

.area {
  display: flex; flex-flow: row wrap; align-items: stretch; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;
  @media (min-width: 768px) { width: 750px; }
  @media (min-width: 992px) { width: 970px; }
  @media (min-width: 1200px) { width: 1140px; }
}

// Navigation component
// ----------

// Variables
@navbar-height:              64px;
@navbar-background:          #fff;
@navbar-border:              #ddd;

@navbar-collapse-breakpoint: 768px;

@navbar-item-font-size:      14px;
@navbar-item-border-width:   4px;
@navbar-item-color:          #555;
@navbar-item-active-color:   #333;
@navbar-item-border:         transparent;
@navbar-item-active-border:  #673ab7;

// Component skeleton
.navbar-component {
  background-color: @navbar-background;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);

  & > .navbar {
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
}

// Component
.navbar {
  // Brand
  & > .brand {
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #777;
    margin: round((@navbar-height - 20) / 2);
  }

  // Toggle button
  & > .toggle {
    border: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    outline: none;
    border: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    cursor: pointer;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    user-select: none;
    padding: round((@navbar-height - 20) / 2);

     @media (min-width: @navbar-collapse-breakpoint) {
       display: none;
     }
  }

  & > .toggle > .icon {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;

    &,
    &:before,
    &:after {
      display: block;
      width: 24px;
      height: 3px;
      transition: background-color 0.3s linear, transform 0.3s linear;
      background-color: #555555;
    }

    &:before, &:after { position: absolute; content: ""; }
    &:before { top: -8px; }
    &:after { top: 8px; }
  }

  & > .toggle.-active > .icon {
    background-color: transparent;

    &:before { transform: translateY(8px) rotate(45deg); }
    &:after { transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg); }
  }

  // List of items
  & > .list {
    display: none;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    align-items: center;
    white-space: nowrap;

    @media (min-width: @navbar-collapse-breakpoint) {
      display: flex;
    }

    @media (max-width: @navbar-collapse-breakpoint) {
      position: fixed;
      top: @navbar-height;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      overflow-y: hidden;
      overflow-x: auto;
      border-top: 1px solid @navbar-border;
      background-color: @navbar-background;
    }

    &.-on {
      display: flex;
    }
  }

  & > .list > .item {
    display: block;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    height: @navbar-height;
    line-height: @navbar-height;
    padding-left: round((@navbar-height - 20) / 2);
    padding-right: round((@navbar-height - 20) / 2);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: @navbar-item-color;
    font-size: @navbar-item-font-size;
  }

  & > .list > .item.-link {
    line-height: @navbar-height + @navbar-item-border-width;
    color: @navbar-item-color;
    border-bottom: @navbar-item-border-width solid @navbar-item-border;

    &.-active,
    &:hover,
    &:focus {
      color: @navbar-item-active-color;
      border-bottom-color: @navbar-item-active-border;
    }
  }
}
```

[I got so far already](https://codepen.io/atocx/pen/JyvaqY)

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 20px;
}
body {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  color: #333;
}
.menu-container {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 64px;
  border: #ddd;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /* Shadow needs position "relative" */
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
  position: relative;
}
.navbar {
  /*border: 1px solid black;*/
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  }
.navbar-right {
  width: 25%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.brand {
  color: #555;
  border: transparent;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
  line-height: 64px;
}
.brand:hover {
   color: #333;
   border-bottom-style: solid;
   border-bottom-color: #673ab7;
 }
.about {
  color: #555;
  border: transparent;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
  line-height: 64px;
}
.about:hover {
   color: #333;
   border-bottom-style: solid;
   border-bottom-color: #673ab7;
 }
.projects {
  color: #555;
  border: transparent;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
  line-height: 64px;
}
.projects:hover {
   color: #333;
   border-bottom-style: solid;
   border-bottom-color: #673ab7;
 }
.contact {
  color: #555;
  border: transparent;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
  line-height: 64px;
  }
.contact:hover {
   color: #333;
   border-bottom-style: solid;
   border-bottom-color: #673ab7;
 }
```

As you can see I tried to do this with basic CSS as I am just learning it and don't know any Less and no JS. 
Only difference I see is that the highlighting of the menu box doesn't stay when clicked and that it doesn't connect to the next menu point as in the example.
I do believe that I can fix the width of the highlight with just pure CSS but I don't know how.

What I don't know if it is possible to let the highlight of the menu point stay when clicked?

Would like some help.

**Update:** 
[So I almost got it](https://codepen.io/atocx/pen/yoEEoW)

To have the highlight stay I used the :focus selector.

```
.about {
  color: #555;
  border: transparent;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
  line-height: 64px;
  padding-left: 22px;
  padding-right: 22px;
}

.about:hover, .about:focus {
  color: #333;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: #673ab7;
}
```

I just didn't get it so that the highlight connects to the next menu point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for.  *EDIT:* I removed the justify right portion, because it isn't needed with `flex-grow`

```
.navbar-right {
    width: 25%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

You had `justify-content: space-around;`, which will add space around elements evenly.

Also do this

```
.about {
    color: #555;
    border: transparent;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
    line-height: 64px;
    flex-grow: 1;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Change your other ones accordingly.

I would highly suggest pulling this out into a different class, since you'd be reusing it a lot.  You could do:

```
.navbar-right a {
    color: #555;
    border: transparent;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
    line-height: 64px;
    flex-grow: 1;
    text-align: center;
}
```

That way you won't have as much duplicate code.

*EDIT:* I added a snippet for you.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 20px;
}

body {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  color: #333;
}

.menu-container {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 64px;
  border: #ddd;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /* Shadow needs position "relative" */
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
  position: relative;
}

.navbar {
  /*border: 1px solid black;*/
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar-right {
  width: 25%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.brand {
  color: #555;
  border: transparent;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
  line-height: 64px;
  padding-left: 22px;
  padding-right: 22px;
}

.brand:hover, .brand:focus {
  color: #333;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: #673ab7;
}

.navbar-right a {
    color: #555;
    border: transparent;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
    line-height: 64px;
    flex-grow: 1;
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar-right a:hover, .navbar-right a:focus {
  color: #333;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: #673ab7;
}

.projects_text {
  background-color: green;
  height: 500px;
}

.contact_text {
  background-color: red;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Florian Dietrich</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="menu-container">
      <div class="navbar">
        <a href="#" class="brand">Florian Dietrich</a>
        <div class="navbar-right">
          <a href="#" class="about">About</a>
          <a href="#" class="projects">Projects</a>
          <a href="#" class="contact">Contact</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <section class="intro">
  </section>
  <section class="projects_text">
  </section>
  <section class="contact_text">
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That would do the trick although this would shift the .navbar-right class a little closer into the mid and the individual items closer together. 
I want it to be distributed like it is and still have the boxes connect.

Comment: You would need to keep this, but adjust your padding of the navbar maybe.  Or wrap the div.  I'll come up with a solution, but I don't know exactly what you want.

Comment: That should get you going.

Comment: But, it doesn't look good on small screens.  You'll need to adjust some things for that.

Comment: Wow okay so if I got this right, you just added the flex-grow property and a text-align property to the anchor tags in the navbar-right class correct?
On small screens I would like to add a feature later on so that the menu points change into this menu symbol? that is used on smartphones. 
Dunno how that would work yet but wanted to get my head around this navbar first without learning JS. 
To have it change into a dropdown icon I think I'll have to add media queries or something? :D
Edit: Essentially that means I wouldn't need the classes for the menu points correct?

Comment: The hamburger menu? Yeah, that's media query heavy for sure. You may not need classes in there. It all depends on how things iron out when you do the hamburger menu, but if there isn't uniqueness between them, you'll likely be better with a generic class, or using multiple selectors like what I did. You probably would want to hide this one and show another one when you're below a certain width.  There are a lot of cool selector things, like selecting the first child of a type, every other, etc. CSS is pretty neat. I like variety, but miss working with CSS as much as I used to.

Comment: This site actually looks pretty good for learning a lot of stuff about CSS. The first few pages teach a lot of things that took me a while to learn through just working on CSS randomly throughout my career. I'm not sure if it is a really good resource, but it should teach you a lot of fundamental things that I didn't realize until after I was pretty deep into the css world http://learnlayout.com/

Comment: @FlorianDietrich, please let me know if there's anything else you require for your question to be answered.